# Not load JS formatter field used Views Infinite Scroll

Tags: views

I had my module formatter field for Image Slide . After load scroll page that field not run slide , I Debug see not include js slide when load scrolled ! So how to include js or call js field formatter after load scrolled ?

Comment: Are you trying to say that your jQuery is not applying to ajax loaded stuff?

Comment: yes ! it is .My jquery not apply to ajax loaded

Answer (score 0):

add an ajax complete function to your js code.

Ex:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    // Do stuff here when ajax loads.
});
```